# Reading file and writing output to diffrent files in python

Tags: python

I have a test.txt file as below:

```
qwerty1

qwerty2

qwerty3
```

I want the output as below:

```
test1.txt will contain: qwerty1

test2.txt will contain: qwerty2

test3.txt will contain: qwerty3
```

Updated Question :

I have this following file md5_list.txt which contains :

1cd2612d20bb729bbb337c75334d082f
377c247fe09fdee4e0d6b4866b943f5b
496ea3b6af0a019ece98382c6f6706ae
50f8d739de466eb38e792fd21a0372f7
53a59d4834b152bb4586e440acbe717d
639efc02c91bdd97576fa622da9b0f13
642323e61d5410ef8492dbaffff1679f
69c526c319263a6f18a989b1d4d20bde
75540fd68c905f596d780515c09c037c
7dcf7ea900e0a6d8750f23ee3835d4c7
7ffd2d935ba9d7f8e2977526cc3390cb
8701a1900489b790a3b6399196656b97
8bae8f92a05821b285e662a16d631588
9840a295bf4845d05eade40bf25b9520
a0e7b1b87fe47badc309feb809b37223
b3d86d9cc68eb882b54ec19d52eda55e
b83fe468d19320f6d43d1b41618c4c0c
bc3ff4638aacd177ccabeccf2d356f0b
c919e36b85be14d882c2a044a0cdc060

19efb22e9e029d55bf072d422586aeda
1a8548465aed313bb45574819753b7d7
23f68ef1abecdce9ea2ce2b24f5574d6
6fee2f31e02e6803c22d1da7fc12882d
75f9066b228c759d32d18b35bd6969e1
7cd610fa3eac844daa57354ee417ccb8
aab1ea896d1abfa200c4b8c6ada9184f
acfa5231fea51b63704d4c861378bae4
b168c6339bb73ec802353d97278f6cd0
baa25de96c40fa467c8dc2019fcaa0df

02ecbbdd0b0d40c6700ee775c141e81a
04bc65050ec685dcc1fe71bc4484dcfd
0665621dc90b37ee5b56c413a0bd9cb0
087835049c74b49d6149cfdb9e4a1de0
0a7bae9e445c5ee662b0be7cd44517c1
0bf40bcf849faad316630eabda585769
11ac5f191063c08383c04bdf3d128282
124426002281d79d859a977187442cff
24777b8f91beabf780d41f73d7246fb7
24e4d9c696787ba913ca4f35a8cdc0d7
2a303cffbdf936c63a875780b64124c3
2dc29d160012134c6d5c885f4c39cee6
33ba3a1455867bcfcf6bd86c5b3260a5
346369e79b9e9ab64eb940b274a3eece
5a3de9157fe4284e522e7afce0e15b76
5a8c3c95773c08d74f94c5aed6f65e0e
63f5fad74b84ccd2d8469b57f053f84b
6798d8a8e86e256cb1976d034e688284
6f202d116530a3d9f4d2dc8cc8ca0abf
80d40818c4165dcdb2016a273588a53f
81f6ec57a6647e8416a256a4b4072d3e
a2f07f4ec811373a9c91a46716864c5c
a5627067aa87ebf3696302f033ccdf08
af4726df4de56b390ea1d5525b1463d1
b38cda28f53f5dc1965e57668e9eca52
bb7eb37fe44f0ac5954202668f5c9515
bc7fc16a7cf2b932cd1fa81b80c8dc55
d1d6c50ce9ad675f8b53fcd325dd4c04
da5587214697c7b879f8ed8bb48213c3
dad8b39ff8960896d6f8a26d37eb15ff

Now I want to get the data in three separate files named as md5_list1,md5_list2,md5_list3.

Required Output :

in md5_list1.txt  :

1cd2612d20bb729bbb337c75334d082f
377c247fe09fdee4e0d6b4866b943f5b
496ea3b6af0a019ece98382c6f6706ae
50f8d739de466eb38e792fd21a0372f7
53a59d4834b152bb4586e440acbe717d
639efc02c91bdd97576fa622da9b0f13
642323e61d5410ef8492dbaffff1679f
69c526c319263a6f18a989b1d4d20bde
75540fd68c905f596d780515c09c037c
7dcf7ea900e0a6d8750f23ee3835d4c7
7ffd2d935ba9d7f8e2977526cc3390cb
8701a1900489b790a3b6399196656b97
8bae8f92a05821b285e662a16d631588
9840a295bf4845d05eade40bf25b9520
a0e7b1b87fe47badc309feb809b37223
b3d86d9cc68eb882b54ec19d52eda55e
b83fe468d19320f6d43d1b41618c4c0c
bc3ff4638aacd177ccabeccf2d356f0b
c919e36b85be14d882c2a044a0cdc060

in md5_list2.txt :

19efb22e9e029d55bf072d422586aeda
1a8548465aed313bb45574819753b7d7
23f68ef1abecdce9ea2ce2b24f5574d6
6fee2f31e02e6803c22d1da7fc12882d
75f9066b228c759d32d18b35bd6969e1
7cd610fa3eac844daa57354ee417ccb8
aab1ea896d1abfa200c4b8c6ada9184f
acfa5231fea51b63704d4c861378bae4
b168c6339bb73ec802353d97278f6cd0
baa25de96c40fa467c8dc2019fcaa0df

in md5_list3.txt :

02ecbbdd0b0d40c6700ee775c141e81a
04bc65050ec685dcc1fe71bc4484dcfd
0665621dc90b37ee5b56c413a0bd9cb0
087835049c74b49d6149cfdb9e4a1de0
0a7bae9e445c5ee662b0be7cd44517c1
0bf40bcf849faad316630eabda585769
11ac5f191063c08383c04bdf3d128282
124426002281d79d859a977187442cff
24777b8f91beabf780d41f73d7246fb7
24e4d9c696787ba913ca4f35a8cdc0d7
2a303cffbdf936c63a875780b64124c3
2dc29d160012134c6d5c885f4c39cee6
33ba3a1455867bcfcf6bd86c5b3260a5
346369e79b9e9ab64eb940b274a3eece
5a3de9157fe4284e522e7afce0e15b76
5a8c3c95773c08d74f94c5aed6f65e0e
63f5fad74b84ccd2d8469b57f053f84b
6798d8a8e86e256cb1976d034e688284
6f202d116530a3d9f4d2dc8cc8ca0abf
80d40818c4165dcdb2016a273588a53f
81f6ec57a6647e8416a256a4b4072d3e
a2f07f4ec811373a9c91a46716864c5c
a5627067aa87ebf3696302f033ccdf08
af4726df4de56b390ea1d5525b1463d1
b38cda28f53f5dc1965e57668e9eca52
bb7eb37fe44f0ac5954202668f5c9515
bc7fc16a7cf2b932cd1fa81b80c8dc55
d1d6c50ce9ad675f8b53fcd325dd4c04
da5587214697c7b879f8ed8bb48213c3
dad8b39ff8960896d6f8a26d37eb15ff

```
for num in range(0,no_of_files) :
        with open('md5_list.txt','r') as file:
            data = file.readlines()
            for i in data:
                if not i.startswith('\n'):
                    with open('md5_list'+str(num+1)+'.txt','a+') as finalfile:
                        finalfile.write(i)
                else:
                    break
```

it is creating the files the only issue is only the first block of data is getting written in each file.

Comment: Show some of your code or effort.

Comment: so you want to write every line to different files?

Comment: please add some of your code and describe what actually you want

Comment: I have updated the question. Sorry for not being specific.Please take a look , if you can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the file in readmode read lines check if line is not newline then write new file.

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as testfile:
    i = 1
    for line in testfile:
        if line != "\n":
            with open("test{}.txt".format(i), "w+") as newfile:
                newfile.write(line)
            i += 1
```

UPDATED:

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as testfile:
    i = 1
    for line in testfile:
        if line == "\n":
            i += 1
        else:
            with open("test{}.txt".format(i), "a") as newfile:
                newfile.writelines(line)
```

Comment: Hey @Fabian, Thanks for answering it completely solved the given scenario but when I'm trying it with the block of data only a single line is getting written to the new file. I have updated the question, i am also adding my code. Please take a look at it. Thanks.

Comment: Done...Solved the issue. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = [i for i in f if i.strip() != '']
    for i,line in enumerate(lines, 1):
        with open('test%s.txt' % i, 'w') as out:
            out.write(line)
```

Comment: Hey @U10-Forward, Thanks for answering it completely solved the given scenario but when i'm trying it with the block of data only a single line is getting written to the new file.